# Power Supply compatibility with ASRock X399 Professional Gaming sTR4 Fatality Motherboard

Tags: motherboard, power-supply

I recently purchased Cooler Master MPY-7501-AFAAG-US MWE 750 Gold Full Modular, 80+ Gold Certified 750W Power Supply ([https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07JW7M3VX/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o06_s01?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07JW7M3VX))
along with a ASRock X399 Professional Gaming sTR4 SATA 6Gb/s USB 3.1/3.0 ATX AMD Motherboard 
([https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B074J6LVBD/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_image_o06_s02?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B074J6LVBD))

This particular motherboard requires a **4** & **8** & **24** pin power.
Problem is that  the PSU only comes with a **8**(split into 2x4 if needed) and a **24** pin ATX power *which leaves me without any power for the* **4 pin connector**. Is there any solution or do I just need to get a new PSU?